# Google Sheets/Excel Parse List in Cell and Add <li> Classes To Each Item

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a list in one cell in Google Sheets:

```
7-Eleven Purchase

Balcony

International Channels

Internet - Wifi

Microwave

Netflix

Smoking Rooms Available

Swimming Pool
```

This does a good enough job of putting them all in a new cell and adding a pipe between them:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"|")
```

But, I need to add link classes to this list so that the output is:

```
<ul><li>7-Eleven Purchase</li>|<li>Balcony</li>|<li>International Channels</li></ul>
```

I have been trying to add the classes to this but to no avail:

```
=CONCATENATE("<li>","</li>",(SUBSTITUTE(H2,CHAR(10),"</li>")),"</li>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
="<ul><li>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),"</li>|<li>")&"</li></ul>"
```

Comment: It is better than what had but keeps adding in a spare empty pair of li classes between each entry, this is because there is a linebreak between each item in the original cells, so it's wrapping a class around them.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
="<ul>"&textjoin("|", 1, index("<li>"&split(A1, char(10))&"</li>"))&"</ul>"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`="<ul><li>"&textjoin("</li>|<li>",true,transpose(split(A1,char(10))))&"</li></ul>"`